# Choices for optimization method with generalized method of moments (GMM) in Python

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels, linear-optimization

How do I find out the options for `optim_method=''` with the generalized method of moments in statsmodels? I've been told by a colleague that simplex method is good for my problem. How do I find out its name, and the names of other available optimizer methods?  I get a `ValueError: Optimizer method not available` when I put in `'simplex'`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.sandbox.regression.gmm import GMM

rand_array = np.random.rand(150, 7)
yvar=rand_array[:, [0,1]]
zvar=rand_array[:, [2,3,4]]
xvar=rand_array[:, [5,6]]
xvar=sm.add_constant(xvar)

class GMMREM (GMM):

    def momcond(self, params):
        b0, b1, b2, b3, b4,m0, m1, m2, m3 = params
        x = self.exog
        z = self.instrument
        y=  self.endog

        error1 = x[:,0]*(y[:,0]-b0-b1*y[:,1]-b2*z[:,0]-b3*z[:,1]-b4*x[:,1])
        error2 = y[:,1]*(y[:,0]-b0-b1*y[:,1]-b2*z[:,0]-b3*z[:,1]-b4*x[:,1])
        error3 = z[:,0]*(y[:,0]-b0-b1*y[:,1]-b2*z[:,0]-b3*z[:,1]-b4*x[:,1])
        error4 = z[:,1]*(y[:,0]-b0-b1*y[:,1]-b2*z[:,0]-b3*z[:,1]-b4*x[:,1])
        error5 = x[:,1]*(y[:,0]-b0-b1*y[:,1]-b2*z[:,0]-b3*z[:,1]-b4*x[:,1])

        error6= z[:,2]*(y[:,0]-b0-b1*y[:,1]-b2*z[:,0]-b3*z[:,1])

        error7 = x[:,0]*(y[:,1]-m0-m1*y[:,0]-m2*z[:,2]-m3*x[:,1])
        error8 = y[:,0]*(y[:,1]-m0-m1*y[:,0]-m2*z[:,2]-m3*x[:,1])
        error9 = z[:,2]*(y[:,1]-m0-m1*y[:,0]-m2*z[:,2]-m3*x[:,1])
        error10= x[:,1]*(y[:,1]-m0-m1*y[:,0]-m2*z[:,2]-m3*x[:,1])
   
        error11 = z[:,0]*(y[:,1]-m0-m1*y[:,0]-m2*z[:,2])-m3*x[:,1]
        error12= z[:,1]*(y[:,1]-m0-m1*y[:,0]-m2*z[:,2])-m3*x[:,1]
    
        return np.column_stack((error1, error2, error3, error4, error5, error6, error7, error8, error9, error10, error11, error12))

model1 = GMMREM(yvar, xvar, zvar, k_moms=12, k_params=9)
b0 = [.01, .08, -.02, 0, 0,.01, 1.7, .05, 0]
res1 = model1.fit(b0, maxiter=100, optim_method='simplex', wargs=dict(centered=False))
print(res1.summary())
```

Comment: Simplex might work, but it will be difficult to demonstrate for your problem since there are many reproducibility gaps in your code.

Comment: Noob mistake.  Edited.

Comment: What is `sm`? `sympy`?

Comment: `GMM` and its members `exog`, `instrument` and `endog` are all still missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only a selection of scipy optimizers are available in GMM fit.
Here is the list in the code https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/main/statsmodels/sandbox/regression/gmm.py#L738

`GMM.fit` does not go through inherited `LikelihoodModel.fit`, so not all scipy optimizers are available.

Note:
Generic `GMM` requires a general nonlinear optimizer for smooth functions, which are available in scipy.optimize.
Only GMM for linear modesl, `LinearIVGMM`, has a special `fit` method that uses linear algebra for an explicit solution.

Comment: Just what I was looking for.  I'm too much of a noob to 'upvote' your answer but much respect to you.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you know how I can find the list of options for LinearIVGMM?

Comment: LinearIVGMM does not have any optimizer options. It uses pinv and does not have any other linear algebra options unlike OLS, https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/_modules/statsmodels/sandbox/regression/gmm.html#LinearIVGMM.fitgmm

Comment: Note, Because your model has two sets of moment conditions, it cannot be written as a simple linear moment equation and does not match the linear IV pattern. It might be possible to use vertical stacking with block diagonal moment conditions instead of horizontal stacking of moment conditions. But I never tried or verified that. (Parameter estimates might or should be ok, but inference might not take the block diagonal structure correctly into account.)

Comment: Thanks for your earlier response!  Do you have any insights on which algorithms are best for the problems like above?  Which bgfs it seems to jump to a suboptimal solution and stay there.

Comment: nelder-mead "nm" is more robust because it does not use derivatives, otherwise "bfgs" or "fmin_l_bfgs_b" are the best of those connected to GMM.fit but require good starting values if there is more than one local optimum.

Comment: However, looking at your moment conditions again. `error2` and `error8` use an endog y as an instrument. Are you sure that's what you want?  The moment condition are for two linear equations, so the solution should be well behaved unless there is too much multicollinearity.

Comment: Yes - this is simultaneous demand and price equations.

Comment: AFAIR, we don't include the endog as instruments. moment conditions are only with exogenous variables and instrumental variables as `instruments`. (orthogonality condition with endog regressor does not hold. Endogenous regressors are correlated with residuals.)

Comment: Also, your instruments z enter the regression equation, so they are also regressors. AFAICS, the only pure instrument (not included as regressor) is x[:,0]. My guess is that convergence problems are because moment conditions are not well defined.

Comment: I'm going to look further into this.  I'm new to GMM and my OLS intuition is that you want all RHS variables, endogenous or not, to be uncorrelated with the error term.

Comment: However, OLS estimates are not consistent if some regressors are endogenous. That's why we switch to instrumental variables or GMM estimation.

Comment: Thought about it more and agree. TYSM